# Is there Quranic evidence that marriages are made in heaven?

Tags: quran, nikah, phrase

I heard that couples are made in heaven. I need quranic evidence for same. Please tell me what is quran ayat regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from [IslamAwareness.net](http://www.islamawareness.net/Fate/fate_fatwa004.html), [IslamHelpline.net](http://www.islamhelpline.net/node/6127) and [KhalidZaheer.com](http://www.khalidzaheer.com/qa/538) the phrase *marriage made in heaven* is just a way of referring to predestination ([qadar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_in_Islam)) in regards to marriage.

None of these links come up with Quranic evidence for the phrase "marriage made in heaven".

Answer (score -2):

بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم

رَبِّ اشْرَحْ لِي صَدْرِي ; وَيَسِّرْ لِي أَمْرِي ; وَاحْلُلْ عُقْدَةً مِنْ لِسَانِي ; يَفْقَهُوا قَوْلِي

وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ أَنْ خَلَقَ لَكُمْ مِنْ أَنفُسِكُمْ أَزْوَاجاً لِتَسْكُنُوا إِلَيْهَا وَجَعَلَ بَيْنَكُمْ مَوَدَّةً وَرَحْمَةً إِنَّ فِي ذَلِكَ لآيَاتٍ لِقَوْمٍ يَتَفَكَّرُونَ

“And among His Signs is this that He created for you wives (spouses) from among yourselves, that you may find repose in them, and He has put between you affection and mercy. Verily, in that are indeed signs for people who reflect.”

(Aayah No. 21, Surah Ar-Rūm, Chapter No. 30, Holy Qur’an).

http://www.quranandhadith.com/husband-wife-relationship/

You can read the complete article here